# Explanation behind the calculation of training loss in deep learning model

Tags: python, deep-learning, classification, loss-function

I am trying to model an image classification problem using convolution neural network. I came across a code on Github in which I am not able to understand the meaning of following line for loss calculation in the training loop.
I am omitting most of the detail and only placing the relevent code-

```
for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(final_train_loader):
     loss = criterion(output,target)
     #Idea behind the below line
     train_loss = train_loss + ((1 / (batch_idx + 1)) * (loss.data - train_loss))
```

Cross-entropy loss function is being used here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line you're asking about

```
train_loss = train_loss + ((1 / (batch_idx + 1)) * (loss.data - train_loss))
```

is basically calculating the average train_loss for the finished batches

To illustrate, suppose 4 batches have been done (with average loss named avg_loss) and current is calculated from 5th batch (with loss named new_loss)

The new average loss is from

$\frac {4 \times \text{avg_loss} + \text{new_loss}} {5}$

This is exactly the same as

$\text{avg_loss} + \frac {\text{new_loss} - \text{avg_loss}} {5}$

which is the calculation done by the code

Comment: Thanks Wang. Could you please explain me in form of some equation or by giving an instance or if you could point to some resources. I am finding it hard to build an intuition of it as I also find the following `train_loss` in many cases-`train_loss += loss.item()*data.size(0)`

Comment: No worries. I've updated with the equations.

Comment: Another noob question, why we multiplied avg_loss with 4?Edit:Oh.. I got it...thanks.

Comment: When calculating averages, we need its total amount. Multiply avg_loss with 4 to get the total amount of loss in the first 4 batches because avg_loss of the first 4 batches is calculated from total amount divided by 4.

Comment: you are really superb